# Rigging Question

Tags: animation, rigging, bones

Ok, so I'm working on creating landing gear and landing gear doors for the model I'm working on, but I haven't done a great deal with rigging armatures in the past. The game I'm modeling this for uses an armature for these functions, so keyframes won't work.

There are a total of three points of articulation on my landing gear door: Two hinges and the actuator arm. On the "real" craft being represented by the model, the hinges are just points of rotation, while the actuator arm is what actually opens and closes the door.

The hinges are also at an angle to the axes on the grid, not parallel, so would have a bit more complex rotation.

Is it possible to rig the door so that it articulates like the actual door would (two linked points of rotation, driven by the actuator acting against the mesh at another point) or would each of these three points need to be rigged and positioned individually?

Comment: You don't have to use an armature [see this tutorial](http://cgcookie.com/blender/cgc-courses/mechanical-rigging-fighter-jet-blender/) and you can find the finished model on blendswap.

Comment: I'm building this model for a game, so I'm pretty sure I'd need an armature for this.

Comment: No sir, just insert keyframes along the way, and the action actuator will do the rest.

Comment: I've confirmed that the particular game I'm modeling for DOES use an armature, so yes, I WILL need to rig this with bones.